# RegEx doesn't match in Perl: Why?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this (German) example string

`Gesundheit und einen besseren Fußball- u. Musikgeschmack!`

I want to match the words that are connected by `- u.`

In this case I want the to match `Fußball- u. Musikgeschmack`
I wrote an RegEx expression which does exactly that but it seems to work differently if I run it as part of a Perl script.

My RegEx is this: `[ |^]*([A-Za-zÄäÖöÜüß]+[\-\\][ ]*[u][\.][A-Za-zÄäÖöÜüß ]+)`
According to this website that allows interactive RegEx testing it selects what it should: https://regex101.com/r/tN6gB4/1

What perl gives me is `ball- u. Musikgeschmack`

I have the German special character `ß` in the block that matches `ball` so I don't get why it does not match `Fußball`

Comment: Did you use `use utf8;`? BTW, `[ |^]*` matches a space, or a pipe or a caret symbols 0 or more times. I think you just wanted `(?:^| *)`. Or even `\b`.

Comment: Thank you that is the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, @stribizhev seem to be right, it's `use utf8;` issue: this pragma says that string literals in the source file are utf8-encoded and thus allow Perl to decode them into Unicode and operate properly.

```
use utf8;
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

$s = "Gesundheit und einen besseren Fußball- u. Musikgeschmack!";

$s=~/[ |^]*([A-Za-zÄäÖöÜüß]+[\-\\][ ]*[u][\.][A-Za-zÄäÖöÜüß ]+)/;
print($1)
```

Output:

```
Fußball- u. Musikgeschmack
```

See also [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) for details.